# Stability of maximum likelihood algorithm with indeterminate forms

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, algorithms, computational-statistics, copula

Assume that I want to estimate a copula model, where the copula has a single parameter, $\theta$. When this parameter takes a specific value, say $\theta_I$, this copula *converges* to the Independence or Product copula: in reality, the random variables involved are independent.

To take a concrete example, the Plackett family of copulas is, for $\theta >0$

$$C_{\theta}(u,v) = \frac {1 + (\theta-1)(u+v) - \Big(\big[1+(\theta-1)(u+v)\big]^2 - 4uv\theta (\theta-1)\Big)^{1/2}}{2(\theta-1)}$$

...and it converges to $uv$ for $\theta = 1$. This is shown by applying L'Hopital's rule. The same will hold for the copula density, which will be of the form

$$c_{\theta}(u,v) = \frac {\text{something}}{2(\theta-1)}$$

Now, $u=F(X), v= G(y)$, where $F,G$ are CDFs with densities $f, g$. I know their functional forms, with unknown coefficients, say $p,q$. The log-likelihood of the sample will be

$$\ln h(\theta;p;q\mid x,y) =  \sum \ln \text{\{something\}}_i - n\ln(2(\theta-1)) + \sum \ln f_i +\sum \ln g_i$$

Now the derivative of the log-likelihood with respect to $\theta$ will include a term $-n/(\theta-1)$...hmm...

Assume that the true value of the parameter is $\theta_0=1$, i.e. the data I have come from independent random variables.

**Will this create troubles and instability to the numerical algorithm as it tries to converge to the true value?**

Perhaps the more general version of my question is:

**Do numerical algorithms handle well in practice situations where mathematically indeterminate forms can be resolved on paper through devices like L' Hopital's rule?**

Comment: That certainly depends on the algorithm! For a good algorithm it should not. For your example, close to $\theta=1$ you could use a taylor approximation.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen This appears to be "tweaking the objective function to handle the algorithm's problems". Perfectly legitimate solution, and thanks for pointing it out, but what would happen to "standard" ready-made algorithms triggered by a software command, eg like Newton-Raphson, or others such? Would they break-down? And if yes, would they break down in an informative way, i.e. in a way that can tell us that the problem likely  is that $\theta$ is indeed close to this special value, and it is not some other problem? I understand that the answer may differ per algorithm of course.

Comment: Then what you are asking about is really robust optimization algorithms. That's not my field @Mark L. Stone ...